# Toyota Yaris transmission problem

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, yaris

2008 Toyota Yaris have a weird problem, It have MMT semi-automatic transmission and last week its change to N itself suddenly. It does not change to 1 when i take to D mode. I wait a while then it work perfectly about 1 kilometer and then happen same thing again. What might it be from?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you checked the fluid level?

Comment: Yes, I checked about three months ago.

Comment: When having transmission problems, it is important to check again. If the fluid is low there may be issues. Also, it would be worth having OBD codes read to see if there is anything stored in there that can help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: You should check the fluid level as a first step, as suggested, three months ago is way too long ago especially as a leak can cause catastrophic loss very rapidly. Once you have checked the level, corrected it as necessary, then you can update your question if the symptoms continue.

Comment: @SolarMike I checked fluid level today and no problem, its normal. But my friend (he is an old Toyota user) told me that may be a temperature problem.

Comment: I found a solution, its about transmission temprature. When the temprature is rises, it change to N mode itself. Because transmission heat sensor is broken. It thought it was always hot. It fixed after changed sensor.